# Side by side figures portrait landscape

Tags: floats, indentation

I am trying to include two figures one is of portrait kind (tall) and other landscape (wide) kind. I am using the code as below

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=\linewidth]{honda_asimo.jpg}
    \caption{Asimo}
    \label{fig:minipage1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.005\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=\linewidth]{BigDog.jpg}
    \caption{Big Dog}
    \label{fig:minipage2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result goes:
[image: The Result]

I want it to just extend to cover the horizontal space which is available to text above(so excluding margins) and want the captions to be centered under the figures.

Comment: I know this is somewhat of a duplicate question but as you can see I have checked the solution and some other internet research but still getting unsatisfactory results. Please help me out thanks a mil

Comment: It would be a real blessing if you would actually test your MWEs.

Comment: sorry about that i posted this in quite some hurry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `addmargin` environment provied by package `scrextend` to help you.

[image: quantumdartFigureStuff]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{addmargin*}[0cm]{-3cm}
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-golden-upright}
        \caption{Asimo}
        \label{fig:minipage1}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-golden}
        \caption{Big Dog}
        \label{fig:minipage2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{addmargin*}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{addmargin*}[0cm]{-3cm}
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-golden-upright}
        \caption{Asimo}
        \label{fig:minipagea}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-golden}
        \caption{Big Dog}
        \label{fig:minipageb}
    \end{minipage}
\end{addmargin*}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```