# How to get two figures beside each other, and have them outside the margins?

Tags: minipage

I have googled forever and tried to find the answer to my question, but I can't seem to find an answer to this. I have two figures that I want to place beside each other. The figures are MATLAB plots and are saved as pdfs, therefore they have to be clipped and scaled to get an okay size in my latex file. I have tried to put the figures beside each other by using minipage and this works, but the figures are too large to fit within the text width, so some parts of the figures are not showing.
Can anyone please help me with this?

As of now my latex code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{addmargin*}[0cm]{-3cm}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim={1.4cm 7.5cm 2.0cm 7.5cm},clip, scale = 0.5]{figure1}
    \caption{Caption one.}
    \end{minipage}  

    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[trim={1.4cm 7.5cm 2.0cm 7.5cm},clip, scale = 0.5]{figure2}
    \caption{Caption two.}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{addmargin*}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Does [Side by side figures portrait landscape](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281556) help?

Comment: No, it does'n really... I still don't get extra margin space. I edited my code to the following, but it doesn't help.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{addmargin*}[0cm]{-3cm}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim={1.4cm 7.5cm 2.0cm 7.5cm},clip, scale = 0.5] {figure1}
    \caption{Flower one.}
    \end{minipage}  
 
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[trim={1.4cm 7.5cm 2.0cm 7.5cm},clip, scale = 0.5] {figure2}
    \caption{Flower two.}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{addmargin*}
\end{figure}

Comment: Also, how do you get the code to look nice like it was edited to in the question?

Comment: In the question, mark the code and press `Ctrl` and `k`. In comments, this does not work. Please edit your question to include the modified code, and please make the exampe compilable. That is the only way, we are talking about the same problem.

Comment: Thank you. The only thing I updated was to add the addmargin part, and that didn't work, so I guess it's okay to keep the code as it is?

Comment: No, it is not. You say it does not work, but it obviously worked in the answer i linked. That means you are doing something different, and [providing a minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) is the only way for us to see the difference.

Comment: Of course, sorry. The code is edited now.

Comment: Without the files figure1 and figure2, there is not a lot we can do.  One thing, if you want them side by side you need to lose the blank line.  That starts a new paragraph.

Comment: for the figure on the left, try `\leavevmode\hspace*(-3cm}\includegraphics ...`; for the figure on the right, insert the negative `\hspace` to the right of the `\includegraphics`.  and lose the blank line between the two minipages as already mentioned.  if you want the captions centered on the graphics, insert the `\leavevmode and `\hspace`s outside the minipages, and end the line with `\par`.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have a `twoside` document then you can ignore the `\ifthispageodd`  line

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newlength\fullwidth
\setlength\fullwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\begin{figure}[!htb]%
   \ifthispageodd{}{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth}}%
   \minipage{\fullwidth}}
  {\endminipage\end{figure}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\newpage\blindtext

\begin{Figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Caption one.\label{bar}}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x10}
    \caption{Caption two.}
\end{minipage}
\end{Figure}

\blindtext
\begin{Figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Caption one.}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Caption two.\label{foo}}
\end{minipage}
\end{Figure}

As seen in Figure~\ref{bar} on page~\pageref{bar} \ldots

\Blindtext

As seen in Figure~\ref{foo} on page~\pageref{foo} \ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Evidently `addmargin` does not change `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{addmargin*}[0cm]{-3cm}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[trim={1.4cm 7.5cm 2.0cm 7.5cm},clip, scale = 0.5]{figure1}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1in}
    \caption{Caption one.}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[trim={1.4cm 7.5cm 2.0cm 7.5cm},clip, scale = 0.5]{figure2}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1in}
    \caption{Caption two.}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{addmargin*}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The point is to use `\linewidth`. It is a list environment.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Corrected.  Thank you.  (Personally, I avoid KOMA as much as possible.)

Answer (score 0):

For such cases is designed the package `changepage`. With its macro `adjustwidth` (for one side documents) or `adjustwidth*` (for two side documents) you will obtain:

[image]

The code for above picture:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{calc}% <--- added
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}% <--- added

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption one.}
    \end{minipage}
\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption two.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: for a _one_ sided document you do not need `changepage`. A simple `minipage` will do

Comment: Yes, in this cases you can stick with `minipage˛` and warning `overfull ... `.  Beside simple use here, the  `changepage` offer consistent flexibility for local  changes of text width. Obvious, I liked this package :-)